# Basis of vectors Graphically

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

How do we check the basis of vectors graphically?
Can anyone explain few of the graphs below How would you know whether they are basis or not
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're talking about pictures, there are only two cases, two-dimensional, and three-dimensional.

In two dimensions, a basis must consist of exactly two vectors, and these vectors can't be colinear.

In three dimensions, a basis must consist of exactly three vectors, and they cannot all lie in one plane.

Comment: Just making sure I got it right. So in the image above only the last two ones are the basis.

Comment: wait 3rd is also basis right?

Comment: nvm got it thanks it is 3rd and 5th